# Main menu slide zoom in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller

Anybody have any idea how to accomplish this?:

http://youtu.be/B1hY47v-31o

I've seen several 3rd party "side panel controller" libraries which allow you to set a "front" and "back" view controller or "left" and "right" view controller and you can get some basic "main menu" type functionality. I think the main difference with this is that the detail view controller's view is compressed as it moves to the right. Another cool thing is that as the main menu is closed and opened, the list items appear and disappear in a staggered manner.

My question is:

1. Does anybody know of a 3rd party library which helps with this?
2. If not, is this easy to implement from scratch or by extending an existing library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu) it is.
Just what you are looking for!

Comment: That said, there are several reasons why you shouldn't use this approach (although it looks cool); most notably because it breaks with the look and feel of iOS apps in that the only place Apple does this is when switching BETWEEN apps; not when interacting with elements within one app. It goes against what the users expect from app behavior.